# mouseReleased() not being called after a mouseDragged() event?

Tags: java, applet, awt, mouseevent

Should a mouseReleased() event be called when the mouse is released after a mouse is dragged?

I need mouseReleased() to be called to reset some variables used in mouseDragged(), but it never seems to be called.

Comment: Are you releasing the mouse inside of the component you are listening on?

Comment: Also, are you using a MouseListener or MouseMotionListener, or both?

Comment: I agree with Paulo -- you may be using a MouseMotionListener but not a MouseListener. Showing code would help, you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Oracle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for a simple method to implement both listeners as Paŭlo asks in his comments

Basically (modified from the link above):

```
//where initialization occurs:
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
addMouseListener(myListener);
addMouseMotionListener(myListener);

private class MyListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    // you may not need this method
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // do your code
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // reset your variables
  }
```